How to prove that the convergence to a steady state exists if the change in transition probabilities are sufficiently slow?
Let's say we have a transition matrix $Q_{n}$ for each time step $n$ of a discrete Markov process, where it doesn't stay stationary for all time steps. I want to prove that if the change between each transition matrix is sufficiently small, that there exists a steady state $P_{ss}$, and that any arbitrary probability vector $P_{n}$ will converge to the SAME steady state i.e. $||Q_{n+1}P_{n} - P_{ss}|| \to 0$ . I was thinking of using the triangle inequality, but I'm not sure how to go about this, I want to show that the above norm will be equal to a constant of the steady state, that decreases when $n \to \infty$.
